# How to inherit the functionality of overloaded operators in C++

Tags: python, c++, inheritance, constructor, operator-overloading

So I have a point class that represents a point in n-dimensional space, and a vector class that inherits from the point class and adds some extra functionality specific to vectors, such as dot products. I want the vector class to inherit the overloaded operators (+, - (unary), - (binary), etc.) from the parent point class. In the original python, I defined the `__add__` operator as such:

```
def __add__(self, other): # should be same dimensionality
    sum = self.__class__.zeros(self.dimension())
    for i in range(self.dimension()):
        sum[i] = self[i] + other[i]
    return sum
```

So it takes self and another object (presumably of the same type), calls a method of the class that generates another point/vector with the same number of dimensions/components and all values of zero, and then fills that point/vector with the added components and returns it. In the python, my vector class inherits this method as is from the point class, and there is no problem because it creates another object of the same class by using `self.__class__` to call zeros (which itself calls the classes constructor with zero values for every argument). I have a C++ version, which looks like this:

```
Point operator+(const Point other) const { // dimensionality must match
    vector<long double> new_comps(_comps.size(), 0);
    for (size_t i(0); i < _comps.size(); i++) {
        new_comps.at(i) = _comps.at(i) + other._comps.at(i);
    }
    return Point(new_comps);
}
```

The problem is that in the C++, I used Point as the return type and called the constructor of the point class directly. Is there any equivalent to `self.__class__.__init__` in C++? More broadly, is there any way to write a member function like this operator so that it calls the constructor of the current class and returns on object of that type, so that the generic function can be inherited and work analogously for each class that inherits it? Or is that sort of behavior not possible in C++, or should I use a different technique (composition instead of inheritance) for this problem? As it is, my vector class inherits from the point class and adds its own member functions just fine, but its + operator returns a point instead of a vector, which is problematic. (To be clear, throughout this I have been referring to the mathematical object of a vector, no the C++ STL container of a vector, though I use that in my implementation.)

Comment: Shouldn't that be `const Point&`?

Comment: Actually, is a Vector really a specialisation of a Point? Wouldn't a Vector be some kind of set of Points?

Comment: Well, technically a vector is just a direction and a magnitude, but it is usually represented as its components in each of the (i, j, k, etc.) directions, just like a point is represented with its (x, y, z, etc.) coordinates. Mainly I used inheritance for the purpose of code reuse, because for all intents and purposes most of their representation and manipulation as objects function the same.

Comment: of course, that one with a bar up top (doh) my brainfade...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring some semantic differences (like is a vector a point), no. What you typically would do instead is make a `static Point zeros()` method that returns a zero'd form of the class, and then call that from the operator overload. If each sub-class implements the method, than it will correctly return the expected type.

Comment: Ok, so that would handle creating an object of the specified type to assign the new value into and then return. What about the declared return type of the function? You can't just set that to `auto`, can you?

Comment: The return type can be the native version. I.E.  `Vector.zeros()` can return a `Vector` and `Point.zeros()` can return a `Point`. Although it obviously must be a subclass of `Point`.

Comment: I mean for the operator+ method. It is defined with return type of point, so when inherited by the vector class it retains that. Is there no way to inherit everything else about the overloaded operator, and just change the return type to that of the derived class, instead of the parent?

Comment: You could likely abstract the actual addition operation to a templated function, and then define `operator+` as `return add_points<Vector>(...);` in vector and `return add_points<Point>;` in point.

Comment: No problem, it can be tricky moving from a dynamically/duck typed language where you don't really have to think about type to a statically typed one where you do.